# Accessing shared folders from Ubuntu (guest OS) in VMware Workstation ACE Edition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, vmware-workstation

I have enabled the "Shared Folders" feature on the VM that runs Ubuntu 9.04. How do I access this from the Ubuntu guest OS?

My host OS is Windows Vista Home Premium with SP2.

Note: I have enabled "Shared Folders" for Windows 7 RC (guest OS) by mapping the //.host/shared folder.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the VMware Tools. Once you have done that and the hgfs kernel module has loaded you should be able to access the shared folders at /mnt/hgfs/

Answer (score 2):

You need vmware-tools installed, which has been problematic in 9.04.
Check out: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/208507

Answer (score 2):

This should help :

- Create the sharefolder on your windows
- Create an account for your linux on windows
- Add your windows ip on you linux hosts file
- then log as root  with su -
- And finally mount the share folder :

  `mount -t smbfs -o username=<Windows system user account>,password=<password> //YourComputer/YourShareFolder /mnt/YourShareFolder`

There is also another method (maybe easier)

- First backup you smb conf file :

  `cp /etc/smb.conf /etc/smb.conf.backup`
- Then edit the smd conf by adding this to the end:

> [SHARE_NAME]
>
> path = /home/user/shared
>
> public = no
>
> writable = yes
>
> printable = no (since you want to share files, not a printer)

- Then restart your smb service :

  `/etc/init.d/smb restart`

These 2 ways work fine for me.

Hope this will help you.